# How to map multiple url pattern in web.xml for Rest controller in spring mvc using tiles

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, tiles

In dispatcher-servlet.xml file, i am having below configuration

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
</bean>


<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

spring-security.xml file

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="true" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login.htm" access="true" /> 
    <intercept-url pattern="/postSocialResponse.htm" access="true" />   
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/socialData/*" access="true" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_SA','ROLE_ADMIN', 'ROLE_LEAD','ROLE_AGENT')" /> 
    <form-login 
        login-page="/login.htm" 
        default-target-url="/" 
        authentication-failure-url="/login.htm?error" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login.htm?logout" />
```

web.xml file

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>socialcare-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>socialcare-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>
```

GetSocialAnalyzedDataService.java file

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/rest/socialData")
public class GetSocialAnalyzedDataService {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    private static SocialAnalyzedDataRepository socialAnalyzedDataRepository= SocialAnalyzedRepositoryImpl.getInstance(); 

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{feedPostUserId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)

    public @ResponseBody String createMessage(@PathVariable String feedPostUserId) throws Exception {
        logger.info("feedpost user id"+feedPostUserId);
        return feedPostUserId;
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me to call this URL using above configuration file.
I am not able to access web service with url pattern http://localhost:8080/FilterRule/rest/socialData/234567

If i am using the below code with http://localhost:8080/FilterRule/rest/socialData/create.htm then it  is working

```
@RequestMapping(value="/rest/socialData")
public class GetSocialAnalyzedDataService {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    private static SocialAnalyzedDataRepository socialAnalyzedDataRepository= SocialAnalyzedRepositoryImpl.getInstance(); 

    @RequestMapping(value = "/create.htm", method = RequestMethod.GET)

    public @ResponseBody String createMessage() throws Exception {
        logger.info("feedpost user id");
        return feedPostUserId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you try adding this to `web.xml`:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>socialcare-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Thanks Ootero for your response. But if i am writing the above code then i am getting the error.Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - cvc-identity-constraint.4.1: Duplicate unique value [socialcare-dispatcher] declared for identity constraint "web-app-servlet-name-uniqueness" of 
  element "web-app".

Comment: So, i have solved it with the below code: <servlet>
  <servlet-name>socialcare1-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>socialcare1-dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/rest/</url-pattern>
  
 </servlet-mapping>